# NodeJS https timeout

Tags: node.js, https

I want to run my node app on HTTP and HTTPS. I have found some code on StackOverflow which I implemented, but I get a timeout when I want to visit the `https://` URL. 
The normal way via HTTP is working fine. And I don't see any error's on the server console when I want to visit the `https://` site. I didn't see anything on the console when I try visit via `https://`

The server is running on the Amazon platform.

Edit: When I start the server I set the `NODE_ENV` variabele to 'production'

```
sudo NODE_ENV=production forever start app.js
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
require('./config/config').set(env);//set configuration
console.log(env);
var config = require('./config/config').config;
var express = require('express');

var debug = require('debug')('juweliergids:server');
var http = require('http');

require('./config/mongoose');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(config.port);
var app = express();
var compact = require('./config/compact')(app, config);

require('./config/express')(app, config, compact);
require('./config/routes')(app, config, compact);
app.set('port', config.port);




/**
 * Create HTTP and HTTPS server.
 */
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port);
httpServer.on('error', onError);
httpServer.on('listening', onHttpListening);

if(env === 'production'){
  var https = require('https');
  var fs = require('fs');

  var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem');
  var certifcate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem');

  var credentials = {
      key: privateKey,
      cert: certifcate,
      rejectUnauthorized:false
  }

  var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
  httpsServer.listen(443);
  httpsServer.on('error', onError);
  httpsServer.on('listening', onHttpsListening);
}

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onHttpListening() {
  var addr = httpServer.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
   console.log('HTTP server is listening on ' + bind);
  debug('HTTP server is listening on ' + bind);
}

function onHttpsListening() {
  var addr = httpsServer.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
   console.log('HTTPS server is listening on ' + bind);
  debug('HTTPS server is listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Have you asserted it's not a firewall issue? Are incoming connections to port 443 allowed?

Comment: That was the solution! Can you place this as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts tend to indicate firewall issues, especially when you don't see anything appear in your logfiles that would indicate that connections are being set up.

So check your firewall if it allows incoming connections to port 443.